# Textbox unsaved value doesn't retain after postback ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have an aspx page with RadioButtonList. When the value is Yes, a textbox (having OnSelectedIndexChanged event) is enabled, and you can add a numeric value.

I also have a hyperlink on this aspx page. When opening the child page and saving the changes for it, it redirects with my parent page. If I didn't save that textbox value, on reload it resets with default value. How to aprevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an aspx page with RadioButtonList. When the value is Yes, a textbox( having OnSelectedIndexChanged event) is enabled and you can add a numeric value. I also have a hyperlink on this aspx page. When opening the child page and saving the changes for it, it redirects with my parent page. If I didn't save that textbox value, on reload it resets with default value. How to aprevent this?

Comment: This answer is a copy of your question. Please delete this answer. BR